# ruby modules and classes same name in structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a folder structure like the following in one of my projects:

- lib

  - bar.rb
  - bar

    - other_bar.rb
    - another_bar.rb
    - next_bar.rb
    - ...

**bar.rb**

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/bar/other_bar.rb")

class Bar
  puts "running BarBase"
end
```

**bar/other_bar.rb**

```
module Bar
  class OtherBar
    puts "running module Bar with class OtherBar"
  end
end
```

If I now run `ruby bar.rb` I get this:

> running module Bar with class OtherBar
>   bar.rb:3:in `': Bar is not a class (TypeError)

I'd like to have a similar structure to a rails model inheritance structure. How can I fix this?  So far as I know ruby does not support this out of the box. Is there a workaround for such a situation?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Bar` can't be a module and a class, they are different things.

Change `bar.rb` to `module Bar` or change `other_bar.rb` to `class Bar`.

Whichever it is, it has to be consistent.  You can't change one to the other. The question is which should it be? If `Bar` is a container for other classes and only has a few global singleton methods? Then it's a `module`. But if it can be instantiated, then it's a `class`.

And yes, you can nest classes. This is totally acceptable:

```
class Bar
  class OtherBar
    puts "running module Bar with class OtherBar"
  end
end

Bar::OtherBar.new # yay!
```

Modules and Classes can be nested inside either other in any way you see fit.

---

Edit with some commented examples to help clear this all up:

```
module Foo

  # Foo::A
  class A
    # simple namespaced class
  end

  # Foo::B, inherits from Foo::A
  class B < A
    # inherting from a class in the same namespace
  end

  # modify Foo::B
  class B
    # When modifying an existing class you don't need to define the superclass
    # again. It will raise an error if you reopen a class and define a different
    # superclass. But leaving it off is fine.
  end

  # nested module Foo::Inner
  module Inner

    # Foo::Inner::C 
    class C
      # simple more deeply namespaced class
    end

    # Foo::Inner::D, inherits from Foo::A
    class D < A
      # inherits from a class in a parent namespace

      # works because ruby looks upward in the nesting chain to find missing constants.
    end

    # Foo::Inner::Foo
    class Foo
      # simple nested class with the same name as something in a parent namespace

      # This is a totally different Foo, because it's in a different namespace
    end

    # Foo::Inner::E, inherits from Foo::Inner::Foo
    class E < Foo
      # class inhereting from another class in the same namespace

      # Foo::Inner::Foo is "closer" than the global Foo, so that gets found as the superclass
    end

    # Foo::Inner::F, which mixes in the gloabl module Foo
    class F
      # the :: constant prefix says to start looking in the global namespace
      # so here we include the top level module Foo, and not the "closer" in namespace Foo::Inner::Foo
      include ::Foo

      # This is an error. This attempts to include the class Foo::Inner::Foo since thats the closest by namespace
      # thing that matches the constant Foo. (you can't include classes, only modules)
      # You need the :: prefix to grab the global Foo module
      include Foo
    end

  end
end

# Z decalred in the global namespace, which inherits from the deeply nested class Foo::Inner::C
class Z < Foo::Inner::C
  # Any class anywhere can inherit from any other class in any namespace.
  # Just drill in!
end

# the following 2 declarations at this point would be identical

# This defines a class deep with in a namespace
class Foo::Inner::Foo::Bar < Foo::A
end

# same as above, but reopens each namespace
module Foo
  module Inner
    class Foo
      class Bar < ::Foo::A
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: how does inheritance work in nested classes?
Does OtherBar already inherit from Bar?

Comment: Nesting is not inheritance. None of the code you or I posted has any inheritance at all. Inheritance is only for classes, never modules, and is done when declaring the class the first time `class Foo < Bar`. Dont confuse nesting and inheritance as they are completely orthogonal.

Comment: ok thanks, thought that already. if I require now OtherBar in Bar, is it just a reopening of this class?

Comment: Correct. Which means the order you load files matters. The first time you define a class or module you are declaring it. Every time you define a class of the same name after that you are modifying the existing one instead, even though the syntax doesn't change.

Comment: what happens, if I have a module which contains a class. this class inherits from another class in this module. and I have a third class which is also in this module. this class is nested in the second one. do i have to declair the inheritance in this class also?

Comment: See my edit, its got a ton of example of different nesting/inheritance scenarios.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that a class should not be used as a namespace https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2017/03/why-you-should-not-use-a-class-as-a-namespace-in-rails-applications/

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that just like classes you can have two modules with the same name in _two different namespaces_

Answer (score 6):

Just use `class Bar` instead of `module Bar`. In Ruby, classes can be reopened and added to.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended not to use a class as a namespace, especially if you use Rails.

If you want to keep the Bar class in `lib/bar.rb`, an option is to move the other classes in the Bars namespace in `lib/bars.rb`.

Read more as to why here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2017/03/why-you-should-not-use-a-class-as-a-namespace-in-rails-applications/

Update: this behavior is fixed in ruby 2.5

See: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/10/18/ruby-2.5-has-removed-top-level-constant-lookup.html