# Disambiguating a class and a module in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.4

I am trying to move a ruby on rails app from ruby 2.3.4 to ruby 2.4.1, the app has a class called Warning however ruby 2.4 has added a core module called Warning. Is there an easy way to disambiguate the class ?

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261474/ruby-modules-and-classes-same-name-in-structure

Comment: Not convinced, https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Warning.html is the new core module. It seems a bit harsh to make you rename your classes randomly....

Comment: The easier way would be to encapsulate the class under your App's namespace `AppName::Warning` and then release a new major version